# Laravel | Problem send email with variables

Tags: laravel, email

I have a problem send email with variables.
I recived this error:

```
 $login is undefined
```

view loginsucesso.blade.php

```
<p>Foi efetuado login na plataforma. {{ $login['nome'] }}</p>
```

Controller:

```
$login = array (
   'nome' => "NAME TESTE"
);
Mail::to($request->email)->send(new emailteste($login));
```

Mail/emailteste:

```
class EmailTeste extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $login;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($login)
{
    $this->login = $login;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{

   return $this
   
    ->subject('Plataforma - Acesso efetuado com sucesso ')
    ->view('email/loginsucesso')
    ->with(['login'=>$this->login]);
   
    
  }
 }
```

I try pass array $login to view and recive error $login is undefined
Thanks!

Comment: Show the error stack trace. Are you sure this is the login it is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs;

> Typically, you will still pass data via the mailable class' constructor; however, you should set this data to protected or private properties so the data is not automatically made available to the template. Then, when calling the with method, pass an array of data that you wish to make available to the template:

So I think your public property is conflicting with the data passed to the view.  Do one or the other, not both.